# OrientDB match {class} returns no results

Tags: match, orientdb, orientdb2.2

When querying OrientDB (2.2.x) using SQL - match, a simple query to match all documents of a particular class fails to return any results while a seemingly equivalent query using a 'select' statement works just fine.

for example, this query returns 0 results:

```
match {class:ClassA} return $matches
```

where, this query returns the 100 records I would expect:

```
select * from ClassA
```

In my database, there are 100 records of type "ClassA". I can see in the Schema Manager that ClassA is defined and has 100 records associated with it. Also, selecting "Query All" from the manager returns all 100 records correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: hello, can you mark it as resolved? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `return $matches` (equivalent to `return $patterns`) returns only results for pattern nodes that have an alias defined. In your case none of them have one. To make it work you can

- add an alias to the node:

  ```
  match {class:ClassA, as:a} return $matches
  ```
- or replace `$matches` with `$paths` (that also returns nodes without an alias):

  ```
  match {class:ClassA} return $paths
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?  I think you should use the select and match together to get the right data, match will only match the criteria but when we need properties, we need to add them to select explicitly.

This query worked for me for my Member class.

```
     select member.firstName, member.lastName, member.email from (MATCH {class: Member, as:member} return member);
```

Well, I am 2 days old into OrientDB so there could be better anwers here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write each property you want to select you can do this :

```
SELECT expand(classa) FROM (match {class:ClassA, as:classa} return classa)
```